# Is a Kivy app using Pulp compatible with Android?

Tags: kivy, kivy-language, pulp

I am trying to create a Kivy app which involves linear optimization using Pulp. The app works fine on my laptop but when I deploy on my Android Phone using buildozer, it fails to load (even if I just import Pulp modules and not actually use them). I include Pulp in the spec file and don't get any error while deploying.
Example - This app fails to load on Andriod but when I remove pulp imports it works -

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.screen import Screen
from pulp import LpMaximize, LpProblem, LpStatus, lpSum, LpVariable, LpSolverDefault
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel, MDIcon
from kivymd.font_definitions import theme_font_styles
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget



class DemoApp(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        screen = Screen()

        label = MDLabel(text="check", halign="center", theme_text_color="Error",
                                font_style="Subtitle2", pos_hint={'center_x': 0.4, 'center_y': 0.9}, id = "test")
 

        screen. add_widget(label)
        return screen

DemoApp().run()
```

Does this mean Pulp is not compatible with Kivy or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: To be clear, the question is whether Pulp can work on Android, not whether it is compatible with Kivy. As you note in the question, you've already verified that it works with Kivy (and this is to be expected as Kivy doesn't care what other libraries you use).

Comment: To find out what's actually wrong, you need to [get the logs](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/android.html#debugging-your-application-on-the-android-platform). It may be that Pulp has e.g. native code that works only on desktop platforms. I had a quick look at its github page but it wasn't clear to me whether it expects to use a pure Python fallback (which should work).

Comment: Thanks for the link. I was able to resolve the issue with the help of logs. Somehow the test module was not getting downloaded for Pulp when installing via the spec file. I downloaded the package directly from git and placed it under the kivy app folder which fixed the issue.